# Insert asp.net Membership-generated UserId into custom table (vb)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, asp.net-membership

I've spent a couple of hours trying to find the answer to this, and although there are tutorials all over the 'net none of them work for me (or I am too n00b to understand what they're telling me...)

Anyway, I'm creating users in asp.net using Membership. What I want to do is add the generated UserId to a column in a custom table I've created, to link the stuff in the custom table with the user created in aspnet_Users.

Here's the code I've got for the registration submit button:

```
Private Sub submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("edinsec").ConnectionString
    Dim createStatus As MembershipCreateStatus
    Membership.CreateUser(fname.Text, password.Text, email.Text, sq.Text, sa.Text, False, createStatus)

    ''#Something has to happen here!

    Dim insertSQL As String

    insertSQL = "INSERT INTO clients (UserId)"
    insertSQL &= "VALUES (@userId)"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(insertSQL, con)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstname.Text)


  Try
      Try
    con.Open()
      Catch ex As SqlException
    MsgBox("Connection Problem - Please Retry Later", 65584, "Connection Error")
      End Try
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      MsgBox("Thank you for joining us - we will be in touch shortly.", 65600, "Join Up")
      Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
  Catch Err As SqlException
      MsgBox("Error inserting record - please retry later.", 65584, "Insertion Error")
  End Try
  con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

As you can see I'm trying to grab the Membership-generated userid and insert it into the clients table. I've tried numerous approaches to grabbing the UserId but none work.

Membership works to create the user, it's just the part afterwards that I'm stuck on.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it in the end using this code:

```
Dim userid As Guid = New Guid(Membership.GetUser(username.Text).ProviderUserKey.ToString())
```

...where username.Text is the content of the username form input, where the user chooses their username.

The relevant parameter line is this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", g)
```

I get a warning about the method I'm using being deprecated, but it works at least!

Comment: The warning related to using .Add instead of .AddWithValue. After changing that, there's no warning and it still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Membership.CreateUser returns a MembershipUser object. You can get the UserId from that returned object.

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser(...);
Guid userId = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
```

Comment: I'm getting all kinds of errors with that code ("MembershipUser is a type and cannot be used as an expression" etc etc). Is that VB you've posted?